# an algorithm to find what does it do

Tags: c++

I've an algorithm and I and don't know what does it do, and what's its complexity, can anyone help me?

```
PUZZLE (A:int[], L:int, R:int)
{

// Assume L, R >0 and L <= R

If( L = R) Then

  return A[L];

double Temp1 :=PUZZLE(A,L, (L+R)/2);

double Temp2 :=PUZZLE(A, 1 + (L+R)/2,R);

If(Temp1 < Temp2) Then

return Temp1;

else Then

return Temp2;

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem even C++.

Comment: the first step is to figure out what programming language it is written in.

Comment: @Jack This is Microsoft Objective-Visual Pascal++.

Comment: @H2CO3: It's dot-net!

Comment: i think it is for MIN-Max problem . but not sure.But it's written wrongly.

Comment: This is more of a pseudo code notation...

Comment: where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code computes the minimum value present in a subsequence of a sequence A. The subsequence begins at index i and ends at index j. Your algorithm could be translated in english as:

```
puzzle(A, i, j) :
  if the subsequence has only one element :
    return this element
  min-left is the minimum value present at the first half of the subsequence(it's computed recursively)
  min-right is the minimum value present at the second half of the subsequence(it's computed recursively)
  return the minimum of min-left, min-right
```

The complexity of this algorithm is obviously lineral(O(N)). But, if you don't believe me, I will prove it for you using the master theorem(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Let T(N) be the recurrence of your algorithm. Then:

```
T(N) = 2T(N/2) =>
T(N) = 2T(N/2) + Theta(1) =>
T(N) = Theta(N) (from the first case of the master theorem, which states
that if f(N) = O(N^logb a-e), for e>0, then the complexity is Theta(N^logb a),
where a=2, b=2, f(N)=Theta(1), and e=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the minimum for a given array within a given interval.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems to be part of feed forward [neual network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). check its wiki for more informaion